# Getting output null for this program for every thread

Tags: java, thread-local

my output:-
Customer Thread - 1....executing with customer id :null
Customer Thread - 4....executing with customer id :null
Customer Thread - 3....executing with customer id :null
Customer Thread - 2....executing with customer id :null

Please explain why null in every case. Why value not incrementing`enter code here`

package test;

```
class CustomerThread extends Thread {
    static Integer custId = 0;

    private static ThreadLocal tl = new ThreadLocal() {
        protected Integer intialValue() {
            return ++custId; //This ++custId is not incrementing
        }
    };

    CustomerThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "....executing with customer id :" + tl.get());?// tl.get() is not getting the values
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomerThread c1 = new CustomerThread("Customer Thread - 1");
        CustomerThread c2 = new CustomerThread("Customer Thread - 2");
        CustomerThread c3 = new CustomerThread("Customer Thread - 3");
        CustomerThread c4 = new CustomerThread("Customer Thread - 4");
        c1.start();
        c2.start();
        c3.start();
        c4.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW: if all you want to do is to assign a start counter it is most likely best to avoid thread locals, just use a field with or constructor argument or initialiser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually set() and get() to interact with the ThreadLocal variable:

```
class CustomerThread extends Thread {
    private static int customerID = 0;

    private static ThreadLocal tl = new ThreadLocal<Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Integer initialValue() {
            return ++customerID;
        }
    };

    CustomerThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void run() {
        tl.set(tl.get());
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "....executing with customer id :" + tl.get());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Customer Thread - 1....executing with customer id :1
Customer Thread - 3....executing with customer id :3
Customer Thread - 4....executing with customer id :4
Customer Thread - 2....executing with customer id :2
```